# replacing special characters in attribute values for xml

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, replace, xquery-sql

I need to update xml column in a table to remove the special char(%) for a particular node Rating Ratingtype="unknown". Special characters present in nodes other than mentioned above should not change. Below are my input and desired results.

```
            Input xml:
            <Ratings>
              <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
                <AppliedKnowledge value="Yes%">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
                <ToolSkills>3.5</ToolSkills>
              </Rating>
              <Rating Ratingtype="known">
              <AppliedKnowledge value="%Yes%">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
                <Experience>9.5</Experience>
                <Education>16.0</Education>
                <DbDevelopment>4.5</DbDevelopment>
              </Rating>
              <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
                <AppliedKnowledge value="%No%">4.0</AppliedKnowledge>
                <ToolSkills>4.5</ToolSkills>
              </Rating>
            </Ratings>

            Expected output xml:
            <Ratings>
              <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
                <AppliedKnowledge value="Yes">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
                <ToolSkills>3.5</ToolSkills>
              </Rating>
              <Rating Ratingtype="known">
              <AppliedKnowledge value="%Yes%">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
                <Experience>9.5</Experience>
                <Education>16.0</Education>
                <DbDevelopment>4.5</DbDevelopment>
              </Rating>
              <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
                <AppliedKnowledge value="No">4.0</AppliedKnowledge>
                <ToolSkills>4.5</ToolSkills>
              </Rating>
            </Ratings>
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the `%` sign is a wanted sign somewhere?

Comment: Yes..as shown in above input XML.. I need the % sign for AppliedKnowledge tag in Rating Ratingtype="known" node..where as in nodes Rating Ratingtype="unknown" i need to remove all % sign

Comment: Raj, please check my edited answer!

Comment: @shnugo...I should have added this point as well..my xml column tree structure could differ from each value, like root element could be Ratings or SuperRatings, So is there a way we can do this dynamic.?

Comment: Hi Raj, please provide one or two examples of actual XML. A dynamic approach will not work other than with a loop. This is slow and ugly... But sometimes necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your last question, there is no easy going.

The `.modify()` method will allow one change per call. This means you'd have to work with some kind of loop.

Still there are approaches:

#### If the `%` is not used anywhere else you might simply do this:

Cast the XML to `VARCHAR`, do a simple text replace and cast it back

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@YourXml AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'%','')  AS XML)
```

#### Better than the loop would be this

Shred the XML down and build it up again. Use the `REPLACE` on the target value only:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<Ratings>
  <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
    <AppliedKnowledge value="Yes%">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
    <ToolSkills>3.5</ToolSkills>
  </Rating>
  <Rating Ratingtype="known">
    <AppliedKnowledge value="%Yes%">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
    <Experience>9.5</Experience>
    <Education>16.0</Education>
    <DbDevelopment>4.5</DbDevelopment>
  </Rating>
  <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
    <AppliedKnowledge value="%No%">4.0</AppliedKnowledge>
    <ToolSkills>4.5</ToolSkills>
  </Rating>
</Ratings>';

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@x AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'%','')  AS XML)

SELECT R.value('@Ratingtype','varchar(max)') AS [@Ratingtype]
      ,CASE WHEN R.value('@Ratingtype','varchar(max)')='unknown'
            THEN REPLACE(R.value('(AppliedKnowledge/@value)[1]','varchar(max)'),'%','')
            ELSE R.value('(AppliedKnowledge/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') END AS [AppliedKnowledge/@Value]
      ,R.value('AppliedKnowledge[1]','varchar(max)') AS [AppliedKnowledge]
      ,R.value('ToolSkills[1]','varchar(max)') AS [ToolSkills]
      ,R.value('Experience[1]','varchar(max)') AS [Experience]
      ,R.value('Education[1]','varchar(max)') AS [Education]
      ,R.value('DbDevelopment[1]','varchar(max)') AS [DbDevelopment]
FROM @x.nodes('/Ratings/Rating') AS A(R)
FOR XML PATH('Rating'),ROOT('Ratings')
```

The result

```
<Ratings>
  <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
    <AppliedKnowledge Value="Yes">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
    <ToolSkills>3.5</ToolSkills>
  </Rating>
  <Rating Ratingtype="known">
    <AppliedKnowledge Value="%Yes%">3.0</AppliedKnowledge>
    <Experience>9.5</Experience>
    <Education>16.0</Education>
    <DbDevelopment>4.5</DbDevelopment>
  </Rating>
  <Rating Ratingtype="unknown">
    <AppliedKnowledge Value="No">4.0</AppliedKnowledge>
    <ToolSkills>4.5</ToolSkills>
  </Rating>
</Ratings>
```